# AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration, module.war must exist and be a directory

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, google-eclipse-plugin

I'm using the latest GAE java sdk and eclipse plugins for eclipse luna.
My project consists of Java modules using maven ([like here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java)).

When I'm trying to deploy the ear project from eclipse, I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Application directory '--PATH-TO-MY-DEV-SERVER--/module-1.0.war' must exist and be a directory.
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.reportConfigException(EarHelper.java:92)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.getApplicationDirectory(EarHelper.java:192)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readEarInfo(EarHelper.java:116)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.readEarConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:203)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:150)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newEarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:66)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newEarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:53)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
... 3 more
```

The referenced modules are not unpacked on deployment. They only exist as .war files!

I've imported the project using maven import from within eclipse. I've also created new workspaces and deleted and cleand the server directory several times. No success so far.